# Update only on the last values included

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run this UPDATE query, but only in the last 121 values included in the table. It is possible?

How I'm doing:

```
UPDATE estrutura q
   SET q.id_horizonte = 
            (SELECT h.id_horizonte 
               FROM horizonte h 
              WHERE q.observacao = h.observacao 
                AND q.nome_horizonte = h.nome_horizonte)
 WHERE id_horizonte DESC 
 LIMIT 121
```

Error I'm receiving:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DESC LIMIT 121' at line 3

Comment: If you were to run a select with that WHERE clause, what would happen?

Comment: The query is nonsensical, so it's hard to fathom what you thought you were doing. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You need to use order by with desc, not where

Comment: I've tried with order by before, but I'm receiving the error: Subquery returns more than 1 row.
But It isn't possibly to returns more than 1 row if the query runs only on the last 121 values included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **seems** that you are trying to update only first 121 values of `estrutura` table (order defined by descending order of `id_horizonte`), using values from the table `horizonte`, employing Join relationship on `observacao` and `nome_horizonte`. Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

One problem in your code is that you are using `DESC` with `Where` clause. `DESC` can only be used with `ORDER BY`.

Another improvement could be changing your query to `JOIN` based instead of using a subquery, in order to determine the value to be set.

Try the following query:

```
UPDATE estrutura AS q 
JOIN horizonte AS h 
  ON q.observacao = h.observacao AND 
     q.nome_horizonte = h.nome_horizonte 
SET q.id_horizonte = h.id_horizonte 
ORDER BY q.id_horizonte DESC 
LIMIT 121
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify the where clause as follows:

where id_horizonte in (select top 121 id_horizonte from estructure order by id_horizont desc)

Comment: Your first error was syntactical. With that resolved you are now seeing that more than one record matches the where clause of your subselect (different error). Have you tried rewriting your query as follows:

Comment: UPDATE q
SET q.id_horizonte = h.id_horizonte
from estrutura q
join horizonte h on q.observacao = h.observacao AND q.nome_horizonte = h.nome_horizonte
join (select top 121 id_horizonte from estructure order by id_horizont desc) x on x.id_horizonte = h.id_horizonte

Answer (score -1):

You could write a procedure where you select the desired entries and then loop through and update them. A different, but very slow and inefficient way would be to modify your where clause to something like this "...where in (subselect)". The subselect should return the IDs of the last 121 entries, of course you would need to format them to fit the right syntax. So if you entirely rely on SQL a procedure would probably be the easiest way of achieving your goal.